# Hooking a command to a CustomDataGridColumn using ICommandSource

Tags: c#, wpf

I am very new to custom controls forgive me for that, but i am trying to Hook a Command to the `SelectionChangedEvent` of a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. It seams that everything is working except my command is null. I am having some trouble why it is still null. Can you please tell me why I am still null and why?

```
   public class CustomComboBoxColumn : DataGridComboBoxColumn, ICommandSource
{
    private bool _canExecute;
    static CustomComboBoxColumn()
    {
    }

    private EventHandler canExecuteChagnedEventHandler;

    #region Dependancy Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the combobox to be editable
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEditableProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsEditable", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomComboBoxColumn), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));
    public bool IsEditable
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEditableProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsEditableProperty, value); }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Command Property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomComboBoxColumn),
        new PropertyMetadata((ICommand)null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCommandChanged)));

    [TypeConverter(typeof(CommandConverter))]
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Command Parameter
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(CustomComboBoxColumn), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Command Target
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandTargetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CommandTarget", typeof(IInputElement), typeof(CustomComboBoxColumn),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(IInputElement)));

    public IInputElement CommandTarget
    {
        get { return (IInputElement)GetValue(CommandTargetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandTargetProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private ComboBox _comboBox;

    public ComboBox ComboBox
    {
        get { return _comboBox; }
        set
        {
            if (_comboBox != null)
                _comboBox.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
            _comboBox = value;
            if (_comboBox != null)
                _comboBox.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    {
        var comboBox = editingElement as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox != null)
        {
            ComboBox = comboBox;
            comboBox.IsEditable = IsEditable;
        }
        return base.PrepareCellForEdit(editingElement, editingEventArgs);
    }


    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FireCommand();
    }

    private void FireCommand()
    {
        if (Command != null)
        {
            Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls OnCommandChanged to hook up new commands
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomComboBoxColumn control = d as CustomComboBoxColumn;
        if (control != null)
            control.OnCommandChanged((ICommand)e.OldValue, (ICommand)e.NewValue);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Calls UnhookCommand and HookCommand
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="oldCommand"></param>
    /// <param name="newCommand"></param>
    protected virtual void OnCommandChanged(ICommand oldCommand, ICommand newCommand)
    {
        if (oldCommand != null)
            UnHookCommand(oldCommand, newCommand);
        HookCommand(oldCommand, newCommand);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Attaches CanExecuteChanged EventHandler
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="oldCommand"></param>
    /// <param name="newCommand"></param>
    private void HookCommand(ICommand oldCommand, ICommand newCommand)
    {
        EventHandler handler = CanExecuteChagned;
        canExecuteChagnedEventHandler = handler;
        if (newCommand != null)
            newCommand.CanExecuteChanged += canExecuteChagnedEventHandler;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Detaches CanExecuteChagned EventHandler
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="oldCommand"></param>
    /// <param name="newCommand"></param>
    private void UnHookCommand(ICommand oldCommand, ICommand newCommand)
    {
        EventHandler handler = CanExecuteChagned;
        oldCommand.CanExecuteChanged -= CanExecuteChagned;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Sets CanExecute
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void CanExecuteChagned(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Command != null)
        {
            RoutedCommand rc = Command as RoutedCommand;
            if (rc != null)
            {
                _canExecute = rc.CanExecute(CommandParameter, CommandTarget) ? true : false;
            }
            else
            {
                _canExecute = Command.CanExecute(CommandParameter) ? true : false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public ViewModel()
{
ChangeDescriptionCommand = new DelegateCommand(UpdateDescription);
}
public DelegateCommand ChangeDescriptionCommand { get; set; }
//..other methods
```

xaml:

```
<icc:CustomComboBoxColumn Header="Item Number"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="Code"
                                          SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                          x:Name="ItemColumn"
                                          SelectedValueBinding="{Binding PartId}"
                                          Command="{Binding ChangeDescriptionCommand}">
                    <icc:CustomComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Parts,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </icc:CustomComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <icc:CustomComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Parts,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </icc:CustomComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        </icc:CustomComboBoxColumn>
```

**Update**
So digging into this much more I found that for some reason the command is not being initialized.

**Update2**
I have created a totally new control referencing [How To Implament ICommandSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748978(v=vs.110).aspx) went step by step and it the slider control from the link worked. I copy pasted into new class changed `Slider` to `DataGridComboBoxColumn` and same issue I was having in my control. null command.

Comment: You post everything except needed XAML and I cant see anywhere `SelectionChangedEvent` .

Comment: @MachineLearning Your method is the standard way to go. If there is no `System.Windows.Interactivity` present, then one can write attached behavior too which is very easy thing to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got called out of the office all day. I have edited and added xaml.

Comment: @Machine Learning I do not want to fire on datagridrow selection changed, i want to fire on comboboxselectionchaned. I will post full control and replace old code

Comment: I see that your update (and digging) does confirm my previous suggestion about InitializeComponent (being missing), that I have  explicitly included in my second answer

Comment: yes, my issue is I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I need to tell you this is a CustomControl, not a usercontrol

Comment: @JamTay317 It is because you don't look at my answer! See I'm binding `Command="{Binding TestCommand, Source={StaticResource VMStatic}}"` You are doing instead `Command="{Binding ChangeDescriptionCommand}"` without a StaticResource Source or equivalent reference/accessor...

Comment: I have looked at your anwser, adding {StaticResource ViewModel} does nothing. as it binds to DataContext by default. I am using a ViewModelLocator.

Comment: It's not just adding  {StaticResource ViewModel}, you should also replace all the other RelativeSource with that StaticResource as I've shown... (and it **does** work) otherwise - if you **really** can't use StaticResource, my last resort option would be a binding done using code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118572/discussion-between-jamtay317-and-machine-learning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are not using `Interaction.Triggers`, here it is a second possible answer.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="CustomDG.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomDG"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyVM x:Key="VMStatic" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemsCVS" Source="{Binding ComboItems}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems, Source={StaticResource VMStatic}}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <local:CustomComboBoxColumn 
                    Command="{Binding TestCommand, Source={StaticResource VMStatic}}"
                         Header="Column With Predefined Values"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding MySubItems, Source={StaticResource VMStatic}}"             

                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedSubItem, Source={StaticResource VMStatic}}"
                    SelectedValuePath="Name" DisplayMemberPath="Name" >
                </local:CustomComboBoxColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CustomComboBoxColumn.xaml

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Class="CustomDG.CustomComboBoxColumn"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomDG"
             mc:Ignorable="d"  >
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" >
            <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="SomeSelectionChanged" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

CustomComboBoxColumn.xaml.cs

```
public partial class CustomComboBoxColumn : DataGridComboBoxColumn, ICommandSource
{
    public CustomComboBoxColumn()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void SomeSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseCommand();
    }
```

### Applying it to your context

> As per my comment, you should put a reference in the **Command** - as well
>   as in the ItemsSource - **Binding**, because the ComboBoxColumn doesn't
>   inherit DataContex

This is your XAML updated, to give you an idea... What I've shown in the section above **does** work and it is tested, here it is more a *tentative*

```
<icc:CustomComboBoxColumn Header="Item Number"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="Code"
                                          SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                          x:Name="ItemColumn"
                                          SelectedValueBinding="{Binding PartId}"
                                          Command="{Binding ChangeDescriptionCommand,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
                    <icc:CustomComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Parts,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                                </Style>
```

### Binding in code

If the above fails, you may resort to binding the Command in the main XAML contructor code-behind (instead of using the main XAML itself) 
Again, the code below is tested and it **does** work.

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Source = this.DataContext;
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("ChangeDescriptionCommand");
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(ItemColumn, CustomComboBoxColumn.CommandProperty, myBinding);
```

Comment: this is the same thing that i am doing, my issue is that my command is null. everything fires when it is supposed to.

Comment: please explain? i don't understand. I'm sorry.

Comment: I am not using the xaml for the DataGridComboBoxColumn

Comment: Please consider marking this as answer or helpful: it should be correct to confirm that it is working...

Comment: Notice my command binding: `Command="{Binding TestCommand, Source={StaticResource VMStatic}}"` Your command is null because your XAML binding is `Command="{Binding ChangeDescriptionCommand}"` and that's not ok for a ComboBoxColumn (that has no DataContext). I've already written this here in this second answer and also in my first one... Again, I think you should accept it as an answer...

Comment: I've added a last resort option: replacing the xaml binding for the Command with a binding done in the code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

The context of the question is a bit unclear to me, but this is how I've managed to make it work (in my understanding of the request).

First of all, I had to design a basic example for the UI

```
<Window x:Class="CustomDG.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomDG"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemsCVS" Source="{Binding ComboItems}" />
        <ContentControl x:Key="TestCmdStatic" Content="{Binding TestCmd}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>


                <local:CustomComboBoxColumn 

                     Header="Column With Predefined Values"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsCVS}}"

                            SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SelectedValuePath="SubName"
                            DisplayMemberPath="SubName" >

                </local:CustomComboBoxColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TestCmd}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I see that the logic behind my `TestCmd` is fired when I change the selection of the Grid items or of the Combo sub-items, so I assume that the original issue could have been in the XAML, that was not shown.

Possible points of attention:

- setting the Interaction Trigger for the event at the `DataGrid` level and
- using a static resource for the binding at the `ComboBoxColumn` level

Answer (score 0):

That may be a dumb question but in you XAML, did you bind your custom property with the actual command of the view model ?

Something like :

```
<local:CustomComboBoxColumn
    Header="My header"
    Command="{Binding ChangeDescriptionCommand}">
</local:CustomComboBoxColumn>
```

However instead of creating your own property for commands, using the existing Interaction mechanism like Machine Learning has shown is much better IMO.